# Past of it'd better be

Tags: past-perfect

I was just watching TV and one of the characters in the show said something like "I don't know what happened there, but it'd've better been good".

Realizing that the deconstruction of that sentence is "it had have better been good" sounds like a tonguestwist, my first impression is that it's incorrect, but if it is, then what construction is actually correct to express the idea of "it would be desirable that it was good"?

Comment: it'd've better been good - It would have better been good. It sounds incorrect in general.
I would say "It would have been better"

Comment: How do you know exactly what the script said? Does the character have excellent English?

Comment: seems confused: "It better have been worth with it!" conflated with "I would have hoped so."

Comment: Suppose he said "...but it have better been good."  That make sense and sounds just about the same.